# No field for creator in ERC721?

Tags: nft, erc-721

As I can see, ERC721  doesn't store the original creator of the NFT. Who is then considered  the creator? The first owner?

Answer (score 2):

There is no notion of original creator in the [ERC721 spec](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721#specification).

The creator could be considered the first person to mint a particular NFT, which you can get by looking for the `Transfer` event that had the `0x0000...0000` address as the `from` parameter (see the linked spec).
The `to` address of this event would be the first owner.